# Set starting directory for gnome-terminal profile

Tags: gnome-terminal

In gnome-terminal if I choose File->"Open Terminal" or "Open Tab" I get a new window in the same directory as the current window.  I would like to create a gnome-terminal profile that starts in a particular directory.  I have experimented with the "run a custom command" option in the "Title and Command" section of the profile's properties, but so far all my attempts result in the terminal immediately exiting.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some testing, and the following worked for me as a custom command:

```
sh -c "cd /path/to/dir; exec bash"
```